# Merging Two Pandas Data-frames where two sets of criteria are met (VLOOKUP EQUIVALENT)

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have been searching high and low on merging two data-frames based on meeting two criteria. Essentially what I am trying to do is vlookup from one data-frame into my main data-frame where date and ticker symbol match.

A basic version of my main data-frame called df1 looks like below. It is the stock symbols that are in an account on 5/1/2016 and 5/2/2016.

```
   Account_Num    Date          Symbol
0     1           2016-05-01    AAPL
1     1           2016-05-01    UA
2     1           2016-05-01    DIS
3     2           2016-05-01    CVX
4     2           2016-05-01    GOOGL
5     2           2016-05-01    PX
6     3           2016-05-01    MOS
7     3           2016-05-01    BLK
8     3           2016-05-01    TMO
9     1           2016-05-02    AAPL
10    1           2016-05-02    UA
11    1           2016-05-02    DIS
12    2           2016-05-02    CVX
13    2           2016-05-02    GOOGL
14    2           2016-05-02    PX
15    3           2016-05-02    MOS
16    3           2016-05-02    BLK
17    3           2016-05-02    TMO
```

My second data-frame df2 holds the prices of the stocks that are in the above accounts on 5/1/2016 and 5/2/2016, looks like this (Made up Prices):

```
   Date          Symbol   Price
0    2016-05-01    AAPL     99.02
1    2016-05-02    AAPL     94.00
2    2016-05-01    UA       43.00  
3    2016-05-02    UA       40.67
4    2016-05-01    DIS      67.88
5    2016-05-02    DIS      70.03
6    2016-05-01    CVX      22.00
7    2016-05-02    CVX      24.47
8    2016-05-01    GOOGL    85.52
9    2016-05-02    GOOGL    84.33
10   2016-05-01    PX       44.22
11   2016-05-02    PX       47.16
12   2016-05-01    MOS      23.77
13   2016-05-02    MOS      21.56
14   2016-05-01    BLK      38.48
15   2016-05-02    BLK      41.22
16   2016-05-01    TMO      67.43
17   2016-05-02    TMO      65.11
```

What I want to end up with is df3 as follows:

```
   Account_Num    Date          Symbol    Price
0      1           2016-05-01    AAPL      99.02  
1      1           2016-05-01    UA        43.00
2      1           2016-05-01    DIS       67.88
3      2           2016-05-01    CVX       22.00
4      2           2016-05-01    GOOGL     85.52
5      2           2016-05-01    PX        44.22
6      3           2016-05-01    MOS       23.77
7      3           2016-05-01    BLK       38.48
8      3           2016-05-01    TMO       67.43
9      1           2016-05-02    AAPL      94.00
10     1           2016-05-02    UA        40.67
11     1           2016-05-02    DIS       70.03
12     2           2016-05-02    CVX       24.47
13     2           2016-05-02    GOOGL     84.33
14     2           2016-05-02    PX        47.16
15     3           2016-05-02    MOS       21.56
16     3           2016-05-02    BLK       41.22
17     3           2016-05-02    TMO       65.11
```

The issue I am seeing is that the two data frames are different lengths, my df1 has 100,000 rows whereas df2 has 23,000. Therefore it's not as if there is a one to one match using the index. The above data-frame examples are very basic, as in the the real data different accounts hold many more stocks than other accounts. So what I think needs to happen is I need to loop through the rows in df1 and bring in the price from df2 where date and symbol match.

I have found examples on the equivalent of a vlookup in Pandas, but it is only matching on one criteria, where as I am looking for date and symbol to match and then pull in the price of the stock on that day.

If anyone knows of info out there on how to do this or has any suggestions it would be greatly appreciated

Thanks,
da4l

Comment: @da41 -Here is hint, you need to "Join" two tables .. You need to create a key in which to join those two tables with something like ->> 2016-05-01AAPL,.  2016-05-01UA...

Comment: Thanks @Merlin I will give that a go now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well thanks to the hint from @Merlin I was able to do what I needed with the following:

```
#cretaed a new column in both data-frames concatenating the Date and Symbol variables called 'DateSym'

df1['DateSym'] = df1['Date'].map(str) + df1['Symbol']
df1

df2['DateSym'] = df1['Date'].map(str) + df1['Symbol']
df1

#then created df3 by merging the two data-frames using 'DateSym' as the index after rearranging so both data-frames had the new 'DateSym' column on the left 

df3 = df1.merge(df2, on='DateSym', how='left')
df3
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is what you want:

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2,on=['Symbol','Date'])
>>> df1.merge(df2,on=['Symbol','Date'])
Account_Num        Date Symbol  Price
0             1  2016-05-01   AAPL  99.02
1             1  2016-05-01     UA  43.00
2             1  2016-05-01    DIS  67.88
3             2  2016-05-01    CVX  22.00
4             2  2016-05-01  GOOGL  85.52
5             2  2016-05-01     PX  44.22
6             3  2016-05-01    MOS  23.77....
```